# How to create floating button with SliverAppbar and add ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

Any idea to create a page with a floating button with Container, ListView using SilverAppBar in Flutter?

I follow this step [How can I put a card into a sliver app bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769270/how-can-i-put-a-card-into-a-sliver-app-bar) it works but cannot add Container below.

[image: Flutter floating button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NestedScrollView solved my problem.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how `NestedScrollView` solved the problem?

Comment: How was this done? I'd also like to know.